# Hibernate Object Eagerly Loads Lazy Collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, collections, lazy-loading

[image]I have a hibernate entity object call project and it has two collections in it called notes and messages like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project")
    private List<Note> notes;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project")
    private List<Message> messages;
    ...
}
```

But for some reason in my test method for getting a project, the notes and messages are already loaded, and my test verifies that:

```
@Test
public void testLoadProjectNotes() {
    Project project = projectDao.getProjectById(41);
    assertNotNull(project.getNotes().get(0));
```

}

I thought a problem could be that I am getting the notes and causing hibernate to load them into the project. Before I execute that statement, though, the debugger shows the notes in the project, before I get the notes.

Here is the method for getting the project by the id:

```
public Project getProjectById(long id) {
    Criteria criteria = new SmartCriteria(getSession().createCriteria(Project.class));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    return (Project) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

So nowhere in the method for getting the project by its id am I getting the results of the notes and the messages.

How do I ensure that the collections I want lazily loaded are being loaded lazily?

Comment: Could you debug at this line `project.getNotes().get(0)`. When you call this, hibernate will send a request to load notes. So if you debug you can see there is no value before calling `getnotes()`.

Comment: That's the thing, there is a value before I execute project.getNotes().get(0).

Comment: from javadoc: "The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed. The implementation is permitted to eagerly fetch data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been specified."

Comment: @sodik ...and it is specified.  Besides which, the default for `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` is to do lazy loading.

Comment: So, what's your JPQL query that retrieves these objects?  If you specify the notes/messages as a fetch join, then you're explicitly overriding the Lazy initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As soon as you call the getter, a lazy loaded collection is initialized. So that statement is by far not usable to detect, if a collection is lazy loaded. If you want to check that, use the method `Hibernate.isInitialized(project.getNotes())`.

Comment: Right, I checked before the getter is called and the notes were already in the project.

Comment: How did you check it?

Comment: Debugger, see picture added to original question

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, when I open the display on the project variable and click on notes or messages, eclipse is calling getNotes and getMessages on the project and thus dynamically loading the notes and messages from the database.